# Inconsistent spelling on Windows 10 LTSC 2019 build 1809 set to English UK

Tags: language, english

I have set the display language on my system to English (UK) but several areas of the Settings app still shows US spellings, sometimes both within the same page, how to fix this?
[image: Inconsistent spellings]

[image]

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: Just how can I fix the issue so that the spellings are consistent with each other, e.g., they should all be "colour" instead of "color".

Comment: You can't? You cannot change the Windows interface in that way.

Comment: The display language is already set to English UK but there are still inconsistencies in the Settings app, as shown by the screenshot

Comment: It wouldn't be the first inconsistency that exists within Windows.

Comment: @Ramhound I know, I might as well just switch the display language back because it makes seense that way.

Comment: Did you install it as US, then change it to UK? Mine is consistent with UK spellings in all the locations you indicate - but mine was always set up as UK, also with a UK keyboard [though I often switch to a US keyboard, that does not change the settings spelling to US]

Comment: @Tetsujin Yeah I did, mainly because I live in a country that uses the US keyboard layout, but I figured I would just change it back because I personally like consistency .

Comment: I'd be hesitant to suggest a reinstall from scratch, as judging by the GPU in your image, the computer isn't officially supported for Win10. [There were initial drivers made for that GPU in 2015, but nothing since.] I'd just put up with it, tbh.

Comment: @Tetsujin I'm not surprised, it is like a decade old, although I upgraded it with the max supported RAM and an SSD when I set up the current install, it works fine for what I use it for, but I do plan to get something better soon (no idea when though).